# Running docker-compose up rebuilds and attaches to other containers

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Locally, I have several sites (using docker4drupal), and generally they are working fine and as expected.  But there are 2 which appear to be conflicting and I cannot see why.

The reason I think they conflict is that if I run one, I can see it start/recreate it's containers correctly.  I then close it, but when I boot the other up, it seems to load up a mix of containers (some for itself, and some which were part of the original site), then it attaches these to the correct containers.

I am new to docker, so sorry if this is too vague, please let me know what information might be useful and I will try to share it.

The main things to note are that I am not running the sites at the same time, that they are using docker4drupal and docker4wordpress, and that `container_name` variable is set differently on the various sites/containers.

---

So the compose files are very long, so here is a snippet from one of them, which shows the mariadb container

```
version: "2"

services:
  mariadb:
    image: wodby/mariadb:$MARIADB_TAG
    container_name: "${PROJECT_NAME}_mariadb"
    stop_grace_period: 30s
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
      MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
```

You can see a more detailed example here: https://github.com/Wodby/docker4drupal

---

An example of the issue I am seeing would be as below.  Note that some start with dan1 and others with dan2:

```
$ docker-compose up
Recreating dan1_traefik
Starting dan2_adminer
Recreating dan1_mariadb
Recreating dan1_mailhog
Starting dan2_solr
Recreating dan1_portainer
Recreating dan1_php
Recreating dan2_apache
Attaching to dan2_adminer, dan2_solr, dan2_mailhog, dan2_php, dan2_portainer, dan2_apache, dan2_traefik, dan2_mariadb
```

Comment: Can you describe a bit more your workflow and specific steps? When/How do you use `docker-compose up/down`, `docker-compose start/stop`?

Comment: Also post the compose file.

Comment: So I have added an example of the compose to the main question now.

My workflow so far has just been to get the site working in docker4drupal.  I haven't really done anything too complex with docker yet, so short of 'just getting it running', my workflow isn't too complex I don't think.  When I am about to start work, I run `docker-compose up`, and than stop it with 'ctrl + c', at which point I then may go to the other sites folder, and do the same there. I have not used start at all, and only used stop on the occassions when I have tried `docker-compose up -d`.

Comment: I have also added an example of the issue I am seeing